# Kotlin Coroutines, decompiled code of a suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm reading Kotlin Coroutines by Tutorials, Chapter 4 - Suspending functions [here](https://www.kodeco.com/books/kotlin-coroutines-by-tutorials/v2.0/chapters/4-suspending-functions) by Ray Wenderlich

However, I'm really struggling to understand the author's explanation of the decompiled code. Would someone be able to explain/describe the path of execution in the decompiled code as it pertains to suspend functions/continuations?

```kotlin
suspend fun getUserSuspend(userId: String): User {
  delay(1000)

  return User(userId, "Filip")
}
```

```java
@Nullable
public static final Object getUserSuspend(
@NotNull String userId,
@NotNull Continuation var1) {
  Object $continuation;
  label28: {
    if (var1 instanceof < undefinedtype >) {
      $continuation = (<undefinedtype>)var1;
      if ((((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label & Integer.MIN_VALUE) != 0) {
        ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label -= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        break label28;
      }
    }

    $continuation = new ContinuationImpl(var1) {
    // $FF: synthetic field
    Object result;
    int label;
    Object L $0;

    @Nullable
    public final Object invokeSuspend (@NotNull Object result) {
      this.result = result;
      this.label | = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      return MainKt.getUserSuspend((String)null, this);
    }
  };
  }

  Object var2 =((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).result;
  Object var4 = IntrinsicsKt . getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED ();
  switch(((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label) {
    case 0:
    if (var2 instanceof Failure) {
      throw ((Failure) var2).exception;
    }

    ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).L$0 = userId;
    ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label = 1;
    if (DelayKt.delay(1000L, (Continuation)$continuation) == var4) {
    return var4;
  }
    break;
    case 1:
    userId = (String)((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).L$0;
    if (var2 instanceof Failure) {
      throw ((Failure) var2).exception;
    }
    break;
    default:
    throw new IllegalStateException ("call to ’resume’ before ’invoke’ with coroutine");
  }

  return new User (userId, "Filip");
}
```

Comment: If you can read the bytecode, I suggest it over the decompiled Java. Also, you can add a simple `println()` before `delay()` to easier identify where is each code fragment. Generally, it reworks the code to save the local state before each suspension point and to allow to jump straight to after each suspension point.

Answer (score 0):

I found this video particularly useful. I've linked the relevant section in the video here: https://youtu.be/YrrUCSi72E8?t=393
at roughly 6:33, where he talks about continuations and labels.

Essentially, when a coroutine is suspended, the continuation is used to save the coroutine state. Once the method is no longer suspended (e.g a result was returned, or the task is done etc.), the continuation's "resume" method recalls the method with the continuation.